# Веб-разработка: стоит ли избегать подпапок в папке images?

Tags: html, веб-программирование, оптимизация-сайтов

Не аксиома, но обычно изображения сайта хранятся в папках типа `img` или `images`. Если в этих папках файлы тщательно организовать по подпапкам, то будет ли это иметь отрицательное влияние (например, на производительность сайта)?

P. S. Прошу не удалять из заголовка часть **Веб разработка:**, а то по заголовку не будет ясно, о разработке чего идёт речь - веб-сайтов, приложений под Андроид или UWP-приложений.

Comment: Люди на сайте ориентируются не по заголовкам, а по меткам к вопросу под ним. Для вопросов связанных с веб-разработкой есть общая метка `веб-программирование`. Просто поставьте ее и все поймут, с чем связан вопрос. Для Android и UWP так же есть свои собственные метки.

Comment: Про вличние подпапок я не в курсе тоже. Некоторые SEOшники говорят, что имя файла может иметь значение для поисковиков, а чтоб папки на что-то влияли — про это не слышал

Comment: Главное что бы сумарная длинна путей и имен файлов не превышала разрешённую длинну заголовка на сервере.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На всех сайтах изображения тщательно организованы по подпапкам. Я пока не замечал, чтобы длина пути к файлу как-то отрицательно влияла на скорость его загрузки. В любом случае, даже если это и так (не знаю в каких условиях такое может произойти), то не организовывать по подпапкам их нельзя, т.к. в противном случае вы потом сами запутаетесь в этих файлах - какой из них какой - и скорость разработки резко снизится.

В итоге на скорость отрицательно влияет скорее неорганизованность папки с картинками, чем ее переорганизованность.